# How to Copy a String variable from (Excel VBA) to Clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

**Goal**: <s>Format cell data,</s> **copy variable from Excel VBA to clipboard for pasting in other applications e.g. "Notepad".**  


<s>e.g. From,</s>

```
FF FF 3F 6B 7D
```

to

```
0xFF 0xFF 0x3F 0x6B 0x7D
```

**Question**: How to get "**0xFF 0xFF 0x3F 0x6B 0x7D**" into Clipboard?

Comment: use Range("A1").Copy where A1 is the cell containing the above hex.

Comment: If your asking how to decorate with 0x; `Replace$(" " & Range("A1").Value, " ", " 0x")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim result As String

result = Process(ActiveCell.Value)

Range("Z2000").Clear            'use a cell far away from your data range
Range("Z2000").Value = result   'assign value to that cell
Range("Z2000").Cut              '& into your clipboard =)
```